# Bootstrap Fixed Bottom Nav Hiding Content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Prenote: Other solutions have not helped. I am seeking a personal solution.

I am using a bootstrap fixed bottom nav, and when my content overflows to the bottom of the page and a scrollbar appears, some content at the very bottom is hidden behind the fixed nav. Here is my fixed nav code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-padded">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="landing.php">MSQUARE.COM</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index2.php">Home</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp; Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</nav>
```

So... I have a jumbotron, a panel, and then a carousel after my nav.
How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 6):

It is because of absolute positioning. you need to add padding-bottom for the body tag so the content moves up.

Usually navbar height is approx 55px 
Hope this helps.

```
 body {
 padding-bottom: 55px;
 }
```